# Can we get an object of class using a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here, i am implementing an GeoMap asset which has all the countries. in this, all countries has their own class such as BTNMongolia, BTNHungary etc. i have only countries name to get object and based on countries name, i want to get object of the country's class. i'm doing like this.

```
function countryObject(country) {
    switch (country) {
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNMongolia();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNHungary();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNComoros();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNAntiguaandBarbuda();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNSouthKorea();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNAustralia();
        case 'mongolia':
            return new BTNTajikistan();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

here, to get object, i want to get object of the country'class from the country'name itself. is there is a short way to do that?.

Comment: amazing each case is same, what really do you want???

Comment: it's result of copy paste.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get object class from string name in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646279/get-object-class-from-string-name-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea as below, you will need to check whether it exist to return null :

```
return new window["BTN" + country.capitalize()]();
```

If your class under a namespace, you may do it this way:

```
return new myspaces["BTN" + country.capitalize()]();
```

As for string `capitalize` you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript).

Comment: Be warned, this doesn't work if your constructors are in a namespace other than `window`

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution. You can use a dictionary like bellow.

```js
function countryObject(country){
    var countryObject = {
        mongolia:  BTNMongolia,
        hungary:   BTNHungary,
        comoros:   BTNComoros,
        australia: BTNAustralia
        // ...
    };
    return new countryObject[country]();
}
```

I've not specified the full code. So please extend it.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate ***every*** one each time the factory function is called - just reference the constructors and `return new countryObject[country];`

Comment: that doesnt really answer his question, its exactly the same as switch-case logic, he still needs to map everything while he asks how to do it blind without mapping...

Comment: @Emissary thanx for the catch, updated my answer now it won't create every time.

Comment: @Emissary ohhh I got it, What I was thinking they both are same, but when you used the terms then I realized, many many thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this questions was already answered here [Get object class from string name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646279/get-object-class-from-string-name-in-javascript).  Basically don't use eval, store the list of classes in a map and then look them up in the map.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like `return eval('new BTN'+country+'()')`. That doesn't seem like a good use of eval, but I can't think of another way of doing it without explicitly listing all the possible classes.